# What is something I should to to help me to Learning SharePoint?

Tags: 2007, asp.net, web-part, learning, training

I have a list of items I was told I should learn below.  Can you tell me if there is one that I should remove and one I can add that will help me learn sharepoint backend development.  I have been working on ASP.net and I have a good handle on Objects (I think) I also have been trying all of the "Hello World" web part examples and failing to get any to finish working.  So I figured I needed some advice to help me learn what I need to be able to start working on SharePoint.  Where I work we have moved to SharePoint and I have SharePoint server for my local machine so I can practice.

I currently use VS 2008 and 3.5 framework and SharePoint 2007.

Thanks for all suggestions.

ASP.NET model

- ASP.NET User Controls
- Intrinsic Objects
  (HttpContext,Application, Request,
  Response, Server, etc.)
- ASP.NET Page life-cycle
- C#
- ASP.NET Web App configuration files
- .NET Namespaces

Object-Oriented/Component Programming

- Properties and Methods
- Events
- Delegates
- Inheritance
- Implementation (interfaces and
  abstracts)

SharePoint Features Development

- Visual Studio SharePoint Project
  Extensions/Templates
- SharePoint Object Model
- Deploying Features using STSADM

Authentication Ticket
Roles Provider

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have been told in the past that if you're developing SharePoint and have grown up in ASP.NET, forget everything you knew about ASP.NET (or rather, don't try to apply everything you learnt about ASP.NET).

If you're just starting out now, you might want to just start on SharePoint 2010 if you have access to a 64-bit system. I suggest this as Microsoft have a released a very comprehensive training kit for SharePoint 2010, available here:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=83a80a0f-0906-4d7d-98e1-3dd6f58ff059&displayLang=en

If you're looking to add to that list, I'd suggest IIS management and maybe SQL server.

At the end of the day, it depends what you want to do - there is far too much to SharePoint development to decide one day that you're gonna learn it. Best start off with a small task then skill up on the prerequisites that you need to know to do that task. Building a simple Web Part to display in a SharePoint web part page is often the first route, then perhaps maybe List Event Receivers.

Comment: Thanks.  I am in an enviroment where I cannot upgrade to 2010 but I do have 2007 at least.  I am a ColdFusion Programmer and where I work they are moving everything to DotNet and SharePoint.  The goal is to move everything we can to SharePoint and those we can't move to DotNet.  I am more of a Coder then a Network Guy.

Answer (score 2):

James has some excellent points here. The other things you may review is some of the training kits for the initial MS cert tests. There's tons of forums and articles on the web, and the number one point I will make is to not underestimate the power of the community. SharePoint has a huge user community, we're all in the business of collaboration, and there's a ton of well respected people in this community that take a lot of time to blog, share experiences, and help when they can. The networking potential is huge.

The other recommendation I'll make is to find your closest SP User Group and try to make those meetings. Events like SharePoint Saturday's are also excellent opportunities to network and learn from some of the brightest people in the community; and best of all, SharePoint Saturday's don't cost you a dime.

Comment: My boss mentioned SharePoint Saturday and I got there right after they sold out here in Baltimore.  I live in Delaware so there are no groups there and I commute 2 1/2 hours one way so I am looking for a group.  I have joined StackOverflow and asked several questions helping me get going on ASP.net.  I am hopefull I can get over the inital hump of NEWBIE Ness (LOL)

Comment: You'll get there soon enough, just know that the community is strong as heck - there's this website, EndUserSharePoint.com, SharePointDevWiki.com and all of our blogs - whatever question you ask you can bet we've all asked the same question at some point in our careers.

Answer (score 2):

I can't recommend any better resource than the [MSDN SharePoint Server Virtual Labs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/cc707678.aspx)

I mean, what more could you ask for than hand picked scenarios, straight from Microsoft, with 90 minutes each on a preconfigured virtual machine you can access over the internet? I guarantee you will be much more comfortable with SharePoint after spending a few hours with these labs. Just look at the list of topics!

- MSDN Virtual Lab: Module 1: Getting Started
- MSDN Virtual Lab: Module 2: Site Structure and Branding
- MSDN Virtual Lab: Module 3: SharePoint for Internet Sites
- MSDN Virtual Lab: Module 4: Forms Based Authentication
- MSDN Virtual Lab: Module 5: Enhancing MySite with Microsoft Live Controls and SharePoint Designer (Live Messenger/Live Contacts)
- MSDN Virtual Lab: Module 6: Customizing Search for your Site
- MSDN Virtual Lab: Module 7: Content Deployment
- MSDN Virtual Lab: Module 8: Building and Deploying a Minimal Publishing Site Definition and Creating a Minimal Publishing Site Collection
- MSDN Virtual Lab: Module 9: Enabling Social Networking for Your Site
- MSDN Virtual Lab: Module 10-2: Integrating a Silverlight Application with the SharePoint Object Model via Web Services
- MSDN Virtual Lab: Microsoft Office SharePoint Server 2007 Enterprise Features Administration
- MSDN Virtual Lab: Microsoft Office SharePoint Server 2007 Installation and Configuration

Answer (score 0):

Classroom training is often a good option too.  Considering your list, be sure that you find a class that focuses on Visual Studio development for SharePoint and not a SharePoint Designer course.  The official Microsoft course is now available: http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/Course.aspx?ID=10175A&locale=en-us.

Andrew Connell (Critical Path Training) offers one via webcast: http://www.criticalpathtraining.com/Courses/Pages/DevelopingSolutionswithSharePoint2010Webcast.aspx

MindSharp also has excellent SharePoint developer course:
http://www.criticalpathtraining.com/Courses/Pages/DevelopingSolutionswithSharePoint2010Webcast.aspx