# SharePoint Training - 2007 or 2010? 

Tags: training, 2007, development, learning

We have SharePoint 2007 and hope to migrate to 2010 sometime.  If I take 2010 will the stuff I learn work on 2007 or should I take 2007?

I am wanting to learn the back end.  Creating Web Parts, etc.  What do I ask the trainers to make sure I am going to get the back end training and not the designer/user training or the SharePoint Engineering training?

I am checking mindsharp.com first does anyone have an opinion on their training?

Comment: you should flag a question with open answer as community wiki

Comment: Okay with me how do you do that? or Since I am new can I even do that?

Comment: @Nathan: Have a read of http://www.sharepointoverflow.com/questions/432/what-does-community-wiki-mean for more info about community wiki. Thanks and welcome to SharePoint Overflow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely start on 2010.  You'll want to download the SharePoint SDK and go through it.  I'm a fan of the MindSharp developer training.  I also think the new Microsoft courses (http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/training/sharepoint.aspx#2010sec3) look good.  Take a look at the links in my other answer: [What is something I should to to help me to Learning SharePoint?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/4870/what-is-something-i-should-to-to-help-me-to-learning-sharepoint/4883#4883)

Answer (score 1):

The API's for any development are similar enough between 2007 and 2010 that going backwards for stuff isn't very hard if you're already a practiced developer.  I'd suggest taking 2010 and keeping the MSDN reference for 2007 handy.

Though be prepared for a major step back in development environment.  It's more difficult to debug and deploy code on SharePoint 2007 than it is in SharePoint 2010.  Often requiring you to be on the server for both.

Comment: My current Dev Box is a server so that should help.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are wanting content specific for SharePoint Development.

Careful with the term "Back End", to most of us this means SQL Server, Windows Server maintenance, IIS, etc.

Comment: Yes.  I mean creating WebParts using Visual Studio and whatever else I need to be able to do a good job with that.

Thanks for making that clear.

Comment: I have no direct experience of training organisations as to date I am self-taught, but there are quite a few organisations out there aimed at directly and quickly training people to very high standards, such as Combined Knowledge, Critical Path, and USPJA(Understanding SharePoint Journal Academy)