# What are some tips for a SharePoint Server?

Tags: 2007, best-practices

I have set up a SharePoint Server as the new Intranet for the company I work for.  I have been thinking that it would be good to have an area where everyone can post ideas and tips they think everyone should know about to get SharePoint servers to do well.  The version of SharePoint does not matter.  If you do talk about a specific version, please label it.

UPDATE: Link in comment below does not work. Correct link is here:
[What is something I should to to help me to Learning SharePoint?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/4870/what-is-something-i-should-to-to-help-me-to-learning-sharepoint)

Comment: Here is a question to learn SharePoint http://www.sharepointoverflow.com/questions/4870/what-is-something-i-should-to-to-help-me-to-learning-sharepoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Know SQL Server. Know how to backup/restore databases, optimise for performance, scalability and high availability. Do this and your environment will run like the proverbial off a shovel.

Answer (score 1):

One tip I have is to use Content Editor Web Parts.  They are very useful to add HTML, CSS, or Javascript to a page.  This should only be done if it needs to be "added" to the page.  If the page needs a change, you will need to look up whether to edit the page's source itself or if you can just use the Content Editor Web Part.